# error with sunspot on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sunspot

I am getting an error on my heroku deployment. Specifically on the page that has the sunspot search.
heroku logs revels:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2997ms
Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2)):
  app/controllers/reports_controller.rb:10:in `index'
```

my reports_controller has

```
def index
  @search = Report.search do           #THIS IS LINE 10
     fulltext params[:search]
     paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 20)
     order_by :created_at, :desc
  end
  @reports = @search.results
```

sunspot.yml

```
production:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8983
    log_level: WARNING

development:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8982
    log_level: INFO

test:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8981
    log_level: WARNING
```

I'm going to guess that my hostname is wrong... but i'm reading that it shouldn't matter. I've tried `$ heroku rake sunspot:solr:start` but that doesn't seem to do anything. What's the issue?

Comment: That production setup isn't going to work on Heroku, basically you can't have a solr instance there, so, in order to fix this you can run your solr instance in different server or you can add this Heroku add-on http://addons.heroku.com/websolr

Comment: $20/month I THINK NOT!!! looks like i will be looking for another solution for search on my app!  thanks for the reply though.

Comment: I suggest going with websolr/sunspot if you can afford it. It's the best option.

Comment: if you have the time to rewrite your app to use ElasticSearch, Heroku has a free addon for that

Comment: I'll look into that, I'm actually just starting a full rewrite on this app now.

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same problem.. I guess you have to get the paid addons get around with this error or you could host Solr server on Amazon EC2 and reference it from Sunspot.yml file..